# Find the next date before a date with a matched ID number Excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a list of data with 200k plus lines. I need to search for the next order date before a certain date, that matches an ID number in excel. I know I can use index match to find the next date before a given date, but how would I do that when I need the ID numbers to match a given ID? I have  attached a sample format of my data I am searching in. The problem is also that I am not search by a range of dates, I need the next date before a certain date. There are multiple dates before a given date, I need to just pull the one before.

Index match formula to find the next given date.

=INDEX(Orders!B:B, MATCH(MIN(ABS(Orders!B:B-F3)), ABS(Orders!B:B-F3), 0))

```
ID  Date
1   7/22/2015
2   4/27/2016
3   7/6/2016
2   4/23/2016
```

Comment: For some reason it is not letting me attach anything. Its basically the ID numbers in column A and dates in coloumn B, then on another sheet, the ID number is column A and the date I need to find the next date before that date, coloumn B.

Comment: You can post the data as text then format it with Ctrl-K.  If that does not work just post the data as text and someone will format it for you.

Comment: ID Date
1 7/22/2015
2 4/27/2016
3 7/6/2016
2 4/23/2016

Comment: Put it in the original post using [edit] not in the comments.

Comment: Thank you Scott. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to state your requirement is to *find the maximal date in `B:B` that is `< F3` and has in `A:A` the `ID` specified in `E3`.* This is exactly what the following formula does:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Orders!B2:B999/(Orders!B2:B999<F3)/(Orders!A2:A999=E3),1)
```

- `AGGREGATE(14, ...., 1)` get the max result in the given array
- The divisions by the criteria will generate `DIV!0` in the array entries that don't match the criteria
- Parameter `6` instructs the function to ignore the error entries, including those divisions by `0`

Notice that although this formula does not require *CSE*, it is array-based, so avoid using *full-columns* because they slow-it down. Choose a reasonable number of rows (i.e. `A2:A999`) that is sufficient to span your data.

Comment: Bonus for using the word *maximal* in the correct context (which I didn't even think was a real word until I googled it).

Comment: @Jeeped lol, thanks. Would've loved the bonus to cover the other 198 words though :P

Comment: Thank you , this seems great! However, I am unable to get it to work. #NUM! is the error I am receiving.

Comment: @ANN that occurs only when no match is found. Please double-check the data and the criteria entered in `E3` and `F3`. Also you might need `<=F3` instead of `<F3`, depends on your ultimate goal.

Comment: Yes ! you are amazing! Thank you sooo very much. This worked wonderfully and I am so happy to learn something new.